# Are these Instruction privileged?

Tags: operating-system

a. Set value of timer.
b. Read the clock.
c. Clear memory.
d. Issue a trap instruction.
e. Turn off interrupts.
f. Modify entries in device-status table.
g. Switch from user to kernel mode.
h. Access I/O device.

I see that all of these are privileged instructions , Am I right ?

Comment: Which architecture are you talking about? It probably would help to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. If switching from user to kernel mode were a privileged instruction, there would be no way to enter kernel mode, except through an interrupt.